# Assign a number to each methods in a package

Tags: java

I'm building Exception Handling in a Java application. When an exception happens, as you know we will have a stack trace. From that stack trace, I will get the top method that is causing the exception and from that method I would like to assign a number as an error code such as E012345, it will be logged along with exception message, stack trace.

For an example, if I have a class com.xyz.foo and method1 and method2 inside class 'foo', I would like to assign com.xyz.foo.method1 to a number like E123456 and com.xyz.foo.method2 to a number like E123457.

When an exception happens inside method1, E123456 will be logged and if exception happens inside method2 then E123457.

I'm looking for a solution which I don't want to maintain a list of methods inside our package and store it in a list or map or file to reduce maintenance efforts.

Looking for something dynamic to generate a number from package.class.methodName so it will work for long run.

Any idea and advice?

Comment: shouldn't be to hard to write a software that analyses your code (e.g. reflection) and assigns a number to each method, maintaining it in a database... but not sure if that will serve to reduce maintenance effort.I would prefer to have the method name logged instead of a code that I must lookup to know where the log entry comes from

Comment: Exception handling is designed so that the programmer can deal with the exceptions. Users should never see exceptions unless there is a programming bug.

Comment: @user15244370 that is what I have done so far. But we would like to remove it

Comment: @NomadMaker the number I'm talking about is not for User. It is for developers only

Comment: @NghiaDo if it is for developers only, why the plain stacktrace is not sufficient? Developers are likely to read method+line number from stack trace rather than use some proprietary system.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want numbers? Your system seems to have many disadvantages in my eyes:

1. not structured
2. may change when you refactor the code
3. not well human-readable

I think you have seen this in Microsoft products or similar software. But these Codes all have a meaning. And they are documented on a webpage or PDF or something similar. If you change the logic (split it in two methods for example) you have to assign a new number to existing logic. I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.

A better option is to create a custom exception class and an enum with all error codes. You can set a description so one enum constant may look like this:

```
FILE_NOT_FOUND(200081, "The file could not be found"),
```

Then you can throw the exception in your code like:

```
throw new MyException(MyErrorCodes.FILE_NOT_FOUND);
```

Another option would be to create an annotation on the method with the error code. Then you can iterate through the stack trace from top until you find a method which has your annotation. You can't just take the first method because it might be some util or library code. But I don't recommend this approach because different causes can make a method to fail.

Comment: This number is NOT a business error code. It is for Debugging purpose. I need to capture  what method is causing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing method name from stack trace frame, you cannot tell off multiple overloads of method with same name. Using line number is slightly better yet fragile (code is changing) and not reliable in 100% cases (for example if whole source is obfuscated and minified on single line).

I think of either

1. some classfile analysing tool or
2. intercepting exception in compile-time weaved AspectJ aspect.

Answer yourself the question whether such overkill is worth doing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you purely want to do

"I would like to assign com.xyz.foo.method1 to a number like E123456 and com.xyz.foo.method2 to a number like E123457."

Then you can go `int number = "com.xyz.foo.method1".hashCode()` which will generate a unique number for each method

Comment: The hashCode of a string is far from being guaranteed to be unique. It's actually surprisingly easy to get accidental collisions.